# Where/How can I get Polygon data from Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I really want to keep this question short, so.. I'd like to know If Google Maps possesses detailed info, in this case I need the polygon **(array of coordinates)** for a particular Municipality inside a city (ie. **Envigado** in the city of *Medellin*, Co)

Is there a way to obtain this type of data?

EDIT: I'm not sure if Google Maps is displaying the type of polygon geographic feature I need, as stated in an answer maybe not, but a simple query shows something interesting:

[image: Envigado probable polygon]

Comment: I need same thing , did you able to achieve same ?

Comment: I asked this Question a long time ago Anita, Maybe the data is available now? As far as I can remember I had to get a map and eye-ball the points I needed on my own.

Comment: I did R&D for all way but unable to get same

Comment: Tough Luck @Anita, I would have hoped they had something like that by now. What municipality are you looking for? (just curious)

Comment: I want to draw polygon to near 50km of my current location , now the problem is from where i can get the polygon cordinates ?

If there is way to maual , what is that ?
for more referance you can see my post on stackoverlfow : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609873/objective-c-google-maps-draw-a-polygon-within-radius-of-50-kilometers-from-my-c

if you hv any idea please let me know 
I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boundaries on the map tiles aren't (currently) available through the Google Maps APIs except via calls to the reverse geocoder (which doesn't return a polygon, just the information for that location).  The Natural Earth data set contains country and state boundaries, but not the level of detail you are looking for.

You could request that feature be added (I don't see an existing request, but you should check before adding one):

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

I think this is the feature request you are looking for:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109

Comment: Hi there, I agree, yesterday I spent about 6 hours trying to figure out how could I retrieve this type of info, and I simply couldn't. However there's one interesting thing, I don't know if this is a coincidence but for the example I posted (ie. Envigado, Antioquia, Co) There seems to be a Polygon, I will edit my question a post a screencap. I'd like you to tell me if what I'm seeing is a Polygon or something else. THANKS, please check back shortly.