# Google Geocoding API, get outline information?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry, google-geocoding-api

When searching Google Maps for a County, State, or Zip code, it will indicate the actual territory boundaries of that area, not just the centerpoint.

When I [use the Google Geocoding API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York,+NY&sensor=false), I get the centerpoint, as well as square boundaries, but I do not get the entire outline shape of the boundaries.

Is it possible to get the entire outline from Google, so that I can, for example, create clickable counties on a map, rather than just a map of centerpoints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where/How can I get Polygon data from Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630696/where-how-can-i-get-polygon-data-from-google-maps-api)