# google map with area boundary or perimeter highlighted

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, kmz

I am trying to make map with javascript with city area highlighted.
Like below when we search in google maps.

[image]

I am aware of drawing polygon on google map.
But for this I need latitude and longitudes on baundary of area.
Any hints on this will be helpfull.

If this boundaries (kml or kmz) can't be obtained from google any direction for source providing them will be helpful.

Comment: Can't (currently) be retrieved from google: feature requests in issue tracker: [Issue 109: Feature: Automatic polygon generation to specified geographic boundary (e.g. state, country)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109) or [Issue 6269: API to get Zipcodes/States/Counties Boundaries](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6269)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where/How can I get Polygon data from Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630696/where-how-can-i-get-polygon-data-from-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 1):

From google this kind of information are not avalaible like suggested in comment by @geocodezip. but you can try search on the website of your national statistical institution or presiding over the management of cartographic information. In many countries it is available for free, or conditions of use that provide for free use, digital maps of all the administrative boundaries of the country. Often this information is available in the shape format but can be easily converted inf KML format using a product as free as QGIS (Quantum GIS)