# How can I get the Polygon data for a location name?

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, openstreetmap, point-in-polygon

I'm looking for a valid source, from where I can get the polygon coordinates for a location.
Is there any API for this?

Does Google maps API provide this polygon coordinates?
What are the other options for this process?
For example, I want to get the **Las vegas** polygon as

```
          bounding_polygon_coordinates=[
            [
              [
                -105.549276,
                35.774311
              ],
              [
                -105.523848,
                35.766057
              ],
              [
                -105.526546,
                35.736796
              ],
              [
                -105.476596,
                35.7116
              ],
              [
                -105.461345,
                35.714209
              ],
              [
                -105.420425,
                35.698977
              ],
              [
                -105.403493,
                35.707495
              ],
              [
                -105.352212,
                35.696013
              ],
              [
                -105.38458,
                35.611916
              ],
              [
                -105.549276,
                35.774311
              ]
            ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where/How can I get Polygon data from Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630696/where-how-can-i-get-polygon-data-from-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

Before answering this question, it's important to identify the way to view how things should get viewed.

A `point` is a `point`. A point has no volume, no distance, no circumference, and no area.  A `point` can be a simple thing having only two dimensions - an X and Y value. Otherwise called `coordinates`.

A `line` is just a bunch of `points` that are connected together.  A `line` is similar to a  `point`.  The `line` has no volume, no circumference, and no area.  A `line` never goes around and crosses itself.  But a `line` does have length.  But that length might not always be the same.  The length of a `line` might be different because the length is based on how the `line` gets measured.

A `polygon` is just a bunch of `points` and `lines` that go around until the last `point` connects to the first `point`.  A `polygon` has volume, has circumference, and has some measurable volume.

To be able to answer this question: " I'm looking for a valid source, from where I can get the `polygon` coordinates for a location. Is there any API for this? ", requires knowing what the location is.   What is the location?  Is the location the coordinate from a GPS or is the location a bunch of `points` and `lines` that are used to make the boundaries of a park or an entire state?

Only after the identity of an object (`point, line or polygon`) is first identified and determined does the question, " `where I can get the polygon coordinates for a location`"  make any sense.  And only after that geo-object is identified does it then become a question in determining which geodata source, which software package (`sf, sp, spdep, raster`, etc... ), or which geo-application (`Google` etc... ) to use become a real question having any significance.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope this makes more sense to you.